# Having trouble incrementing objects inside array in with moongose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I've got an object that looks like this

```
{"_id":"5fb07ab6215679200cef0eb1","user":{"_id":"5fb07437538fcd2870e21a8e","email":"example@example.com","id":"5fb07437538fcd2870e21a8e"},"question":"question?","answers":[{"_id":"5fb07ab6215679200cef0eb2","answer":"Yes","votes":0}],"voters":[],"createdAt":"2020-11-15T00:47:50.156Z","updatedAt":"2020-11-15T00:47:50.156Z","__v":0,"id":"5fb07ab6215679200cef0eb1"}
```

and I'm trying to increase the votes variable by this function using findOneAndUpdate

```
export const castVote = async (id, answersid) =>
  Poll.findOneAndUpdate(
    { id, 'answers._id': answersid },
    { $inc: { 'answers.$.votes': 1 } }
  );
```

As far as i can see calling `castVote("5fb07ab6215679200cef0eb1", "5fb07ab6215679200cef0eb2")` works as in not crashing the server and not giving any errors back, but the votes variable in the answers object doesn't increase so something must be wrong. Is there something obvious I'm missing here?.

Comment: You just need to make sure ids in database is object id? then correct this  `{ _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id), 'answers._id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(answerid) }`

Comment: thanks, got it working by simply dropping the id field which i guess i enough since they're uniquely created

Answer (score 0):

got it working by simply dropping the id field which i guess i enough since they're uniquely created